# Logic of to find height of tree by recursion

Tags: recursion, logic, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the height of a tree. Here's some code I found online. However, I don't understand how it works. I would be grateful if you would explain how this program works.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct n {
    int data;
    struct n *left;
    struct n *right;
};

typedef struct n node;

int height_of_tree(node *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return -1; // Why doesn't the function break here?
    int leftTree  = height_of_tree(root->left); 
    int rightTree = height_of_tree(root->right);
    if (leftTree > rightTree) return leftTree + 1;
    else return rightTree + 1;
}

node *getNewNode(int data) {
    node *newNode  = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data  = data;
    newNode->left  = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

node *insert(node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL) root = getNewNode(data);
    else if (data <= root->data)
         root->left  = insert(root->left,  data);
    else root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

int main() {
    node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 12);
    root = insert(root, 23);
    root = insert(root, 122);
    root = insert(root, 1);
    root = insert(root, 2);
    root = insert(root, -3);
    root = insert(root, -4);

    printf("%d\n", root->right->data);
    printf("%d\n", height_of_tree(root));
}
```

Why doesn't the `height_of_tree` function return?

Comment: I edited your answer to make it better. However, I couldn't understand a lot of what you were asking. Let me know if my edit changed your original question in any way you didn't intend.

Comment: Original question didn't change, thanks for edit. Can you explain how this program works?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you comment which parts of the program you don't understand!

Comment: a function named height_of_tree. I didn't understand how it works

Comment: So you understand insert() function and getNewNode() right?

Comment: I think so, yes, Why did you ask? Recursion in height_of_tree is more complex I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be clear, your piece of program is to find the height of [a binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), in which each node has **at most** 2 children (left and/or right)

So the basic idea behind the  recursion function `height_of_tree(node *root)` is that starting from the root of the tree, we will **find and compare** the `height` of its left node and right node.

To find the height of the left node (or right node), we suppose that the left node and all its children will stand alone as a sub-tree and the node itself is the root. We start to run `height_of_tree` again on such the sub-tree with the left node as a new root (this is why we call it recursion). The same logic also applies to the right node:

```
// Reuse height_of_tree() to find the heights of the left node and the right node
// leftTree here means left tree's height
int leftTree  = height_of_tree(root->left); 
int rightTree = height_of_tree(root->right);
```

Then we begin to compare: If the left node's height > the right node's height, then the root (or their parents) would have the left node's height + 1. And vice versa, if the right node's height > the left node's height, then the root would have the right node's height + 1:

```
if (leftTree > rightTree) return leftTree + 1;
else return rightTree + 1;
```

Finally, the conditional check `if (root == NULL) return -1;` is to check when to stop going down and looking for sub-trees (because there is no more nodes underneath it or we can say node == NULL). We have to check this first before executing other lines of code because `if (root == NULL)`, then we surely don't have the next left/right children.

**Some examples:**

1) When the tree is literally = NULL, then `height_of_tree` will return -1.

```
node *root = NULL;
printf("%d\n", height_of_tree(root)); // Print out -1
```

2) When the tree has only one node, aka the root, then `height_of_tree` will return 0. (Please note that by definition a tree consisting of only a root node has a height of 0)

```
node *root = NULL;
root = insert(root, 12);
printf("%d\n", height_of_tree(root)); // Print out 0
```

3) When the tree has only two nodes, aka the root and one child, then `height_of_tree` will return 1.

```
node *root = NULL;
root = insert(root, 12); // root with value = 12
root = insert(root, 23); // right child because its value 23 > root's value 12 
printf("%d\n", height_of_tree(root)); // Print out 1
```

I will be more elaborate on this third case:

- First, we will start from the tree root, which is 12.
- Because the root is not NULL, we begin to find the height of its left child: `int leftTree  = height_of_tree(root->left);`
- As the left child is NULL, the function `height_of_tree(root->left)` , when executed, will return -1, thus making `int leftTree = -1`
- Then, we begin to find the height of its right child: `int rightTree  = height_of_tree(root->right);`
- The right node now becomes a new tree of only one node, according to example #2 above, we have the height = 0 for a tree of only one node, thus `int rightTree = 0`
- Finally, comparing leftTree vs rightTree, we find out that the rightTree is *taller*, so the root's height will be the rightTree + 1 (its tallest child's height + 1). As a result, the root's height is = `rightTree + 1 = 1`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful and detailed. You are the best!